# Binomial distribution problem with conditioning on an event

Tags: probability

> A student is getting ready to take oral examination and is concerned
> about the possibility of having an ‘on’ day or an ‘off’ day. He
> figures that if he has an on day, then each of his examiners will pass
> him independently of each other with probability 0.8, whereas, if he
> has an off day, this probability will be reduced to 0.4. Suppose that
> the student will pass the examination if a majority of the examiners
> pass him. If the student feels that he is twice as likely to have an
> on day as an off day, should he request an examination with 3
> examiners or with 5 examiners?

### Attempt

Let $A$ be the event that the student passes the oral examination. Let $B$ be the event that student has an 'on' day and then $B^c$ is the event that the student has an 'off' day. We know $P(B)=2P(B^c)$. Therefore,

$$ P(B) = 2(1-P(B)) \implies 3 P(B) = 2 \implies P(B) = \frac{2}{3} $$

Now, by the law of total probability, one has

$$ P(A) = P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|B^c)P(B^c) = \frac{2}{3} P(A|B) + \frac{1}{3} P(A|B^c) $$

Since each examiner either passes him or don't, we can call $X$ to be the number of examiners that passes him.

First case when the number of examiners is $3$, then we want to find, and also given that the students has taken a day 'on',

$$ P(A|B)=  P(X=2)+P(X=3) = {3 \choose 2 } 0.8^2 0.2 + {3 \choose 3} 0.8^3 $$

and

$$ P(A|B^c) = P(X=2)+P(X=3) = {3 \choose 2 } 0.4^2 0.6 + {3 \choose 3} 0.4^3 $$

Now, replace everything above into the equations for $P(A)$.

Now, before I procced to do the case when we have $5$ examiners, is this the correct approach to this problem?

Comment: I don't see any issue.

Comment: In R: `(2/3)*sum(dbinom(2:3, 3, .8)) + (1/3)*sum(dbinom(2:3, 3, .4))` returns
0.7146667, whereas `(2/3)*sum(dbinom(3:5, 5, .8)) + (1/3)*sum(dbinom(3:5, 5, .4))` returns 0.7338667.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability of off day $=\dfrac23$

Probability of on day $=\dfrac13$

If he request $3$ examinations then:

$P[$ pass if $2$ or more examiners pass hin$]$
$$=\dfrac23\left[\binom{3}{2}(0.4)^2\cdot(0.6)+\binom{3}{3}(0.4)^3\right]+\dfrac13\left[\binom{3}{2}(0.8)^2\cdot(0.2)+\binom{3}{3}(0.8)^3\right]$$
$$=\dfrac23\left[0.288+0.064\right]+\dfrac13[0.384+0.512]$$
$$=0.2347+0.2987$$
$$=0.533$$
Suppose, if he requests $5$ Examiners then:

$P[$pass if $3$ or more examiners pass him$]$

$P($pass$)=$
$$=\dfrac23\left[\binom{5}{3}(0.4)^3\cdot(0.6)^2+\binom{5}{4}(0.4)^4\cdot(0.6)+\binom{5}{5}(0.4)^5\right]+\dfrac13\left[\binom{5}{3}(0.8)^3\cdot(0.2)^2+\binom{5}{4}(0.8)^4\cdot(0.2)+\binom{5}{5}(0.8)^5\right]$$
$$=\dfrac23[0.2304+0.0768+0.01024]+\dfrac13[0.2048+0.4096+0.32768]$$
$$=0.2117+0.314$$
$$=0.526$$
Probability of passing is more, if there are $3$ examiners. So, he should prefer $3$ examiners.